# How to combine several views, and draw them on an android canvas

Tags: java, android, android-layout

First, this is my first week at android programming, I am trying to conceptualize how games are built. I have a setup, where I've drawn Several views, I'm just wondering how do I put all the views together, each to its thread, but in such a way they all can interact.

**MainActivity**: flash screen and invokes GameMenuActivity on Load

**GameMenuActivity**: calls GamveMenuView

**GameMenuView**: Keeps Track of scores/names/and launches StationActivity

**StationActivity**: calls StationViewsManager

**StationViewsManager**: hoping to be the class where I draw all objects and keep them together

```
/*
gameView = new GameBackgroundView(this);
movingMeteors = new MovingMeteors(this);
movingSpaceShip = new movingSpaceShip(this);
gameView.setClickable(true);
gameView.setFocusable(true);

gameView.addView(movingMeteors);
gameView.addView(movingSpaceShip);
setContentView(gameView);
this is where I'm not sure how to combine the views and draw them. Perhaps i'm not taking the problem from a right angle. any help will be appreciated 
*/
```

**GameThreadManager**: setups up threads of type StationViews
here's a quick snippet, on its instantiation GameThreadManager(StationViews view) it accepts views, that can be run by the method bellow

```
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
@Override
public void run() {
      long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
      long startTime;
      long sleepTime;
      while (running) {
             Canvas c = null;
             startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
             try {
                    c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                    synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                           view.onDraw(c);
                    }
             } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                           view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
             }
             sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
             try {
                    if (sleepTime > 0)
                           sleep(sleepTime);
                    else
                           sleep(10);
             } catch (Exception e) {}
      }
}
```

**StationViews**: superclass of views, draws transparent background,to handle other views

**StationMeteors**: raining meteors

**StationBackground**: revolving background

**StationDefender**: static, left side of screen and shoots bullets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show varius views over each other you need a layout to add them. Basicly you can create a `RelativeLayout` and set it as your content view by using `setContentView()` and add all of your views into the relative layout by using it's `addView()` method.

By the way, why do you wanna use views? I mean you already used SurfaceView for backgroud. You can also draw meteroids and the spaceship over it. That way performance will be better.

Comment: Actually I don't mean to create different views, I ended up doing it that way because I wanted to keep the meteorites code separate from the scrolling background.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

gameView = new GameBackgroundView(this);
movingMeteors = new MovingMeteors(this);
movingSpaceShip = new movingSpaceShip(this);
gameView.setClickable(true);
gameView.setFocusable(true);

gameView.addView(movingMeteors);
gameView.addView(movingSpaceShip);
setContentView(gameView);
```

Comment: addView won't work because my views are SurfaceViews